# Neo4j Session query doesn't work with @QueryResult

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

When I try to use the `Session` method with a parametrised object of type `@QueryResult`, the method can't hydrate the resulting list:

```
<T> Iterable<T> query(Class<T> objectType, String cypher, Map<String, ?> parameters);
```

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `@QueryResult` is a Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) concept, it is not able to work with the Neo4j OGM `Session` functionality.

What you can do instead is just add the query you want to a repository method of SDN with the `@Query` annotation and have it return a `@QueryResult` with the list embedded inside it. Something like:

```
@Query("MATCH ... ")
CustomQueryResult myCustomQuery(@Param("aParam") String param);
```

Comment: Due to an advanced behaviour I Can't use your solution. I need more power because I have to create the query dynamically. But, under the cover, does SDN use the OGM Session to make the query?

Comment: It does, but SDN can only use OGM functionality; it doesn't work vice versa (which is what you are trying to do). If you want to use the OGM stuff only then you will need to add your custom object to the scanned packages without the `@QueryResult`.

Comment: So the only way to do an ordered query by a variable property name is what I do?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe provide some more context?

Comment: I need to retrieve a list of Node ordered by a property. The property name is variable (i.e. the user can choose for which property to do the sorting). The only solution I found was to create a query dynamically and the session.query

Comment: You can use the other suggestion to use the OGM directly: http://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/reference/#reference:session:loading-entities:cypher-queries. The simplest method is to still use what you are using but return a `@NodeEntity` rather than a `@QueryResult`.